Python parsing a JSON file outputs only one result
I'm pretty new to json, I try to parse two elements (multiple occurences), I'm pretty sure I don't iterate correctly.
My json file:
{
  "data": {
    "chapter": {
      "bibleId": "9f3cb709f9bded60-01",
      "bookId": "PSA",
      "id": "PSA.117",
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "style": "nb",
          "content": [
            {
              "type": "verse-number",
              "style": "v",
              "verseId": "PSA.117.1",
              "verseOrgId": [
                "PSA.117.1"
              ],
              "content": "1"
            },
            {
              "type": "verse-text",
              "verseId": "PSA.117.1",
              "verseOrgId": [
                "PSA.117.1"
              ],
              "verseText": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus."
            },
            {
              "type": "verse-number",
              "style": "v",
              "verseId": "PSA.117.2",
              "verseOrgId": [
                "PSA.117.2"
              ],
              "content": "2"
            },
            {
              "type": "verse-text",
              "verseId": "PSA.117.2",
              "verseOrgId": [
                "PSA.117.2"
              ],
              "verseText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "number": "117",
      "next": {
        "id": "PSA.118",
        "bookId": "PSA",
        "number": "118"
      },
      "previous": {
        "id": "PSA.116",
        "bookId": "PSA",
        "number": "116"
      },
      "copyright": "1969/77 Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft, Stuttgart",
      "verseCount": 2,
      "title": "Psalmi 117"
    },
    "studyContent": null,
    "chapterImage": null
  }
}

Desired output:
PSA.117.1       Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus.
PSA.117.2       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

My output:
PSA.117.1       Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus.

My code:
import json
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for i, verse in enumerate(data['data']['chapter']['content']):
    if i == 0:
        print("%s\t%s" % (verse['content'][0]['verseId'], verse['content'][1]['verseText']))
    elif i == 1:
        print("%s\t%s" % (verse['content'][0]['verseId'], verse['content'][1]['verseText']))


Note that you're doing the exact same thing in both if..else branches, making the if..else superfluous, making the i variable superfluous, making enumerate superfluous.

You want one more loop over the inner content list, and filter the nodes which are of type verse-text:
for chapter in data['data']['chapter']['content']:
    for verse in chapter['content']:
        if verse['type'] == 'verse-text':
            print(verse['verseId'], verse['verseText'], sep='\t')


This one does the job. @mitsuaaki code was ok but with about 31 rows it got 5 results output.

Probably because it also just looked at one hardcoded ['content'][0]. As a rule of thumb: for every list ([]) you need one for .. in.

The issue in your script lies in the way you're iterating through the JSON structure and accessing the verse data.
The JSON structure you've provided has an array content within data['data']['chapter']['content'], which contains only one item (a paragraph), and then within that paragraph, it has an array content containing the verses.
import json

# Load the JSON data
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Get the verses from the JSON structure
verses = data['data']['chapter']['content'][0]['content']

# Initialize variables for storing verse number and text
verse_number = None
verse_text = None

# Iterate through the verse data
for item in verses:
    if item['type'] == 'verse-number':
        verse_number = item['verseId']
        
    elif item['type'] == 'verse-text':
        verse_text = item['verseText']
        if verse_number is not None:
            print("%s\t%s" % (verse_number, verse_text))
            verse_number = None  # Reset verse number for the next verse


Since verse-text nodes contain the verseId as well, I don't see a reason to pay attention to verse-number nodes at all, which just makes this more complicated.

a = data['data']['chapter']['content'][0]['content']
for i, verse in enumerate(a):
    if i == 1:
        print("%s\t%s" % (verse['verseId'], verse['verseText']))
    elif i == 3:
        print("%s\t%s" % (verse['verseId'],verse['verseText'])) 

